# Renesas e2 studio (Eclipse-based IDE) fails to path correct during project compilation

Tags: windows, eclipse

I've been trying to use a new install of e2 studio. During compilation, the auto-generated Makefile fails path correctly.

The output of compilation is as follows.

```
make all 
The system cannot find the path specified.
'Building file: ../src/test.c'
make: *** [src/test.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/test.o' failed
```

I believe this to be a problem with the program configuration though I can't find where, or how.

I have tried to compare the configuration settings against the old install, build a barebones project from scratch (that produced the above error) using the automatically generated Makefile, and compiling programs I had written with the previous version.

Does anyone know what would be causing this and how to fix it?

**Edit:** This is the default PATH variable

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201902-SP1-GNURX-ELF\rx-elf\rx-elf\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201902-SP1-GNURX-ELF\rx-elf\rx-elf\libexec\gcc\rx-elf\4.8.4.201902-GNURX\;C:\Renesas\e2_studio\Utilities;C:/Renesas/e2_studio/eclipse//features/com.renesas.jre.win32.win32.x86_1.8.0.181/jre/bin/client;C:/Renesas/e2_studio/eclipse//features/com.renesas.jre.win32.win32.x86_1.8.0.181/jre/bin;C:/Renesas/e2_studio/eclipse//features/com.renesas.jre.win32.win32.x86_1.8.0.181/jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RL78 4.9.2.201902-GNURL78-ELF\rl78-elf\rl78-elf\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201902-SP1-GNURX-ELF\rx-elf\rx-elf\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RL78 4.9.2.201801-GNURL78-ELF\rl78-elf\rl78-elf\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201801-GNURX-ELF\rx-elf\rx-elf\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201803-GNURX-ELF\rx-elf\rx-elf\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\8 2019-q3-update\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2017-q4-major\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q2-update\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.9 2015q3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\Users\jarney\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RL78 4.9.2.201801-GNURL78-ELF;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201801-GNURX-ELF;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201803-GNURX-ELF;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RX 4.8.4.201902-SP1-GNURX-ELF;C:\Program Files (x86)\GCC for Renesas RL78 4.9.2.201902-GNURL78-ELF;;C:\Renesas\e2_studio\eclipse
```

I'm also using 'GCC for Renesas ***'.

Comment: It is difficult to figure out the issue. Can you post an image of the PATH variable?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena I just added it to the question.

Comment: I suggest that you post the question in the [Engineering Stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) and tag the question as **Embedded System** question to improve your chance to get a good response.

Comment: Are you using a RL78 or RX110 micro controller?

Comment: Good idea. I'm using an RL78 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Following are Step that I use to create bare bone Test Project using E2Studio 7.5 for Renesas RX micro controller.

1. File > New > C/C+ Project => Selected the following option

[image: New C/C++ Project]

2. Create a Test Project by creating a Project Name Test

[image: New Renesas CC-RX Executable Project]

3. Make sure the correct tool chain is selected with the appropriated target device. In this example I selected RX130 80pin form factor. Select the **Next** option

[image: New Renesas CC-RX Executable Project - Tool Chain]

4. Make sure Smart Configurator is option is selected

[image: Smart Configuator]

5. This should create an Empty Test Project as follows

[image: Empty Project]

6. Select Project > C/C++ Project Setting => Then Selected Resources > Linked Resources and review the path variables

[image: Linked Resources]

7. Check C/C++ Build > Environment. The entries should look like something below.

[image: Build Environment]

8. Finally select Project > Build All => Look for output similar to the one below

[image: Console Output]

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Hi. I have a different Toolchain installed but continued as described. I encountered the same pathing issue albeit with a different file.

`make -j8 all 
The system cannot find the path specified.
'Building file: ../src/smc_gen/r_pincfg/Pin.c'
src/smc_gen/r_pincfg/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/smc_gen/r_pincfg/Pin.o' failed
make: *** [src/smc_gen/r_pincfg/Pin.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
The system cannot find the path specified.
'Building file: ../src/smc_gen/r_bsp/mcu/rx110/mcu_clocks.c'`

Comment: Are you using RX110 micro controller? Are you using a starter kit or a custom board? How is the clock configured? Some additional details might be useful.